# Implementing retain functionality of SAS in pyspark code

Tags: pyspark, sas

I am trying to convert a piece of code containing the retain functionality and multiple if-else statements in SAS to pyspark.. I had no luck when I tried to search for similar answers.

Input Dataset:

| Prod_Code | Rate | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ADAMAJ091 | 1234.0091 | 1 |
| ADAMAJ091 | 1222.0001 | 2 |
| ADAMAJ091 | 1222.0000 | 3 |
| BASSDE012 | 5221.0123 | 1 |
| BASSDE012 | 5111.0022 | 2 |
| BASSDE012 | 5110.0000 | 3 |

I have calculated the rank using `df.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(window.partitionBy('Prod_code'))).orderBy('Rate')` function 
The value in `Rate` column must be replicated to all other values in the partition containing rank from 1 to N

Expected Output Dataset:

| Prod_Code | Rate | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ADAMAJ091 | 1234.0091 | 1 |
| ADAMAJ091 | 1234.0091 | 2 |
| ADAMAJ091 | 1234.0091 | 3 |
| BASSDE012 | 5221.0123 | 1 |
| BASSDE012 | 5221.0123 | 2 |
| BASSDE012 | 5221.0123 | 3 |

`Rate` column's value present at rank=1 must be replicated to all other rows in the same partition. This is retain functionality and I need help in replicating the same in Pyspark code.

I tried using `df.withColumn()` approach for individual rows, but i was not able to achieve this functionality in pyspark.

Comment: it would be great if you provide samples of input and desired output of your data

Comment: sorry, i cannot provide the datasets due to privacy concerns. please help me to implement the above functionality in pyspark

Comment: can you create dummy data? just to show how the logic goes because it will help us who don't really know SAS

Comment: actually this is the small piece of code i have posted, the original code is 400 lines long and cannot be copied here :( so creation of dataset will be a tough task

Comment: @AdibP, please check the input and expected outputs and help me through it

Comment: your *Rank* column, was it the maximum value of *Rate* for each *Prod_code*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already had *Rank* column, then you can use `first` function to get the first *Rate* value in a window ordered by *Rank*.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import first
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df.withColumn('Rate', first('Rate').over(Window.partitionBy('prod_code').orderBy('rank')))
df.show()

# +---------+---------+----+
# |Prod_Code|     Rate|Rank|
# +---------+---------+----+
# |BASSDE012|5221.0123|   1|
# |BASSDE012|5221.0123|   2|
# |BASSDE012|5221.0123|   3|
# |ADAMAJ091|1234.0091|   1|
# |ADAMAJ091|1234.0091|   2|
# |ADAMAJ091|1234.0091|   3|
# +---------+---------+----+
```

Comment: This is good, but the use actually did not need the retain statment in pyspark or SAS, because SAS also has a 'first' operator.